# ViewModel retrieves empty List but it should not be empty (mutableStateOf)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need some data from a Viewmodel in my `MainActivity` to use it in another composable. So I've tried it with a `mutableStateOf()` to get it out of the viewModel after it fetched the data and updates the values.

```kotlin
private val locationList: MutableState<MutableList<LocationScaffold>> = mutableStateOf(mutableListOf())

                composable(route = Screen.LocationDestinationListScreen.route) { navBackStackEntry ->
                    val factory = HiltViewModelFactory(LocalContext.current, navBackStackEntry)
                    val viewModel: LocationViewModel =
                        viewModel("LocationDestinationListViewModel", factory)
                    locationList.value = viewModel.locationList.value
                    Log.d("viewModel", "${viewModel.locationList.value}")
                    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
                    LocationDestinationListScreen(
                        viewModel = viewModel,
                        lifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner,
                        navigation = { navController.navigate(it) })
                }

                composable(
                    route = Screen.BoxScreen.route + "/{locationId}",
                    arguments = listOf(navArgument("locationId") {
                        type = NavType.IntType
                    })
                ) { navBackStackEntry ->
                    val factory = HiltViewModelFactory(LocalContext.current, navBackStackEntry)
                    val viewModel: HistoryViewModel = viewModel("HistoryViewModel", factory)
                    val activeLocation: Int? = navBackStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("locationId")
                    activeLocation?.let {
                        BoxScreen(viewModel, locationList.value[it])
                    }
                }
```

These are the navigation composables.
`LocationDestinationListScreen` starts a scan for BT Devices and fetches some data from a Server
also there is a `LazyColumn` which shows the result of the data fetching what means that `viewmodel.locationList.value` is definetly not empty and gets updated, but unfortunately not on the `MainActivity` side. Am I missing something here or what have I forgotten?

Because as far as I understand the Flow is:

1. Composable gets built
2. startScan in composable starts
3. on found the method calls `locationList.value` in the viewmodel which updates the data
4. the data runs through the composable and should update all data

I find this kinda weird because on other navigations it works fine like:

```kotlin
                composable(route = Screen.LoginScreen.route) { navBackStackEntry ->
                    val factory = HiltViewModelFactory(LocalContext.current, navBackStackEntry)
                    val viewModel: LoginViewModel = viewModel("LoginScreenViewModel", factory)
                    when (viewModel.authenticationState.value) {
                        AuthenticationStateListener.Loading -> CenterLoadingIndicator()
                        AuthenticationStateListener.Authenticated -> {
                            navController.navigate(Screen.StartScanScreen.route)
                            if (user.value.name.isNullOrEmpty()) user.value = viewModel.user.value
                        }
                        AuthenticationStateListener.NotAuthenticated -> viewModel.openRequestDialog(
                            this@MainActivity,
                            "Something went wrong",
                            R.drawable.ic_baseline_error_24
                        ) { _, _ -> }
                    }
                    LoginScreen(viewModel = viewModel)
                }
```

This also listens to a `MutableState` and it gets correctly redirected after the state value gets changed.